# How do you set up spdlog?

Tags: c++, logging, include, spdlog

I have added a git-submodule for spdlog, and when I try including it like so: `#include "spdlog/include/spdlog/spdlog.h"` I get errors: `spdlog/include/spdlog/spdlog.h:12:10: fatal error: spdlog/common.h: No such file or directory
 #include <spdlog/common.h>`. Am I supposed to run any commands before using this library?

Comment: How do you build your project? Probably you have to set the include path.

Comment: @ThomasSablik I just write on the terminal `g++ main.cpp -obinaries`

Comment: You need to add the include path for sdplog, e.g. `g++ main.cpp -Ipath/to/sdplog -obinaries`

Comment: Thanks @ThomasSablik, it works now!